# Get only results from table "products" if they have entries in two other tables (identified by ID and product type columns)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with "products" that stores a product ID and product type (string).

I'd like to retrieve all those "products", joining them to two other tables that list two individual products and ignore all other products that are not found in these two tables. I have the "product_type" inside the "products" table.

Here's a sample structure:

1. Table `products` (ID, idProduct, type)

   1|3|tv

   2|4|tv

   3|13|phone
2. Table `tvs` (ID, name)

   3|Sony

   4|Phillips
3. Table `phones` (ID, name)

   13|Samsung Galaxy

Even if there are duplicate idProduct values in `products` we are identifying/joining by also checking the `type` column. Currenly, my approach using `LEFT JOIN` to both tables does not work correctly, because it doesn't return any values in case `proucts` contains only one type of product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM products p
LEFT JOIN tvs tvs ON tvs.id=p.idProduct AND p.type="tv"
LEFT JOIN phones phones on phones.id=p.idProduct AND p.type="phone"
WHERE (tvs.id IS NOT NULL OR phones.id IS NOT NULL)
```

Self answer, but I think others might find it useful.

The trickyp part is the `OR` in the `WHERE` condition. We are doing a LEFT JOIN, but we must also check if the product exists in the first OR second table.

Comment: interesting - i was going to sugested using union but this seems simpler. Question - why the double table name? ('LEFT JOIN tvs tvs' and 'LEFT JOIN phones phones')

Comment: doesn't look like a double table name, its just alias.

Comment: @Aditya sure - but an alias is supposed to be used to shorten a table name - here he just doubles the table name - it feels wastefull to create an alias with the same name as the table - that was my point

Comment: Also not sure this really solves any problem. Suuposedly idProduct serves as foreign key to both tvs and phones. Unless he has situations where idProduct is null for some reason he would just get full products table - if he does have nulls checking for nulls would be a better option. If he doesn't have nulls but has idProducts that don't act as foreign keys that just feels like bad design - not knowing his actual situation it's hard to give advice on a better way to do what he needs

Comment: @537mfb Yes, the idProduct serves as foreign key to those two tables based on the 'type', but it serves as foreign key to other product types as well - e.g. `toasters`. I'd like to filter/get products that match only these **two** product categories (I know you can say that I can just check `WHERE products.type IN('phones', 'tvs')`, but that column is not reliable in my case and may be null).

Comment: @WordPressDeveloper if the column is not reliable you might have problems down the line. Be carefull with that. Since you don't say what you mean by not reliable i can't give any advice regarding the issue

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a union - so you can get data from the other tables rather then just products table:

```
(SELECT p.ID, p.idProduct, p.type, t.name
FROM products p, tvs t
WHERE p.idProduct=t.ID AND p.type = 'tv')
UNION
(SELECT p.ID, p.idProduct, p.type, t.name
FROM products p, phones t
WHERE p.idProduct=t.ID AND p.type = 'phones')
```